# Include external files (not libraries) in a project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project ‘P’ in directory ‘P’. I want the use a css file in ‘P’ but the css file is not in directory ‘P’. It is at one level above ‘P’. Could I still include/use the css file in ‘P’ without changing the directory structure or making a copy of the css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add directories outside of the root project directory:

> Project Structure → Modules → Sources → Add content root

[image]

Then after adding a directory, you can see it under your project root.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vojtech. I was able to include the directory following but am facing another issue now. Could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299361/unable-to-include-external-files-in-a-project

Comment: No problem, I've answered your other post also.

Comment: Hey Vojtech, I notice that even though I could add external files, I get this warning `Module is imported from sbt. Any changes made in its confiuration may be lost after reimporting`. Everytime I close and restart IntelliJ, my external folder disappears and I have to add it again. Would you know how to solve the issue using `sbt`?

Comment: In that case on the same screen try 'Import module' using the green + icon above 'rest-demo'