# unable to include external files in a project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created the default play application in IntelliJ in directory `P`. I have over-written the default `index.scala.html` with my own html code. The html code refers to some `css` and `js` files which are outside the directory `P`. To include these external files, I added the directory of these files using project configuration settings.

My webpage doesn't load properly as the server returns `404` for the `css` and `js` files. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you added your directory using project structure, you only say:

> Hey, IDEA, please consider this folder part of my project, consider
>   its contents source code and display it when I open my project.

However, when you deploy or run your app, you only deploy the usual folders to the server, which contain the resources which will be available for clients to access.

The external directory is not part of these directories and will not be deployed.

What you can do is to copy the file from the external directory as a part of your build process before deploying the application.

EDIT: Detailed answer here: [What is intellij's build process for play applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302662/what-is-intellijs-build-process-for-play-applications/48337846#48337846)

Comment: Thanks. I thought IntelliJ would do that if I mark them as source or resources. So now I'll have to learn `sbt` to find out how to do it! Another interesting task.

Comment: Could you recommend some tutorials I could read to understand how intellij builds and deploys play application. I suppose `play` website could be a start but the tutorials there could be difficult to follow at times!

Comment: I don't know exactly about sbt, but I usually use either Pluralsight, Udemy or safari books online and look for content with good reviews.

Comment: Hey, I was able to solve my problem. Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302662/what-is-intellijs-build-process-for-play-applications/48337846#48337846